# My system can't shutdown or suspend

Tags: suspend, power-management, shutdown, 20.04, gigabyte

I just installed Ubuntu (20.04) on my new system (Ryzen 3600 with Gigabyte B450 Aorus M), and my system simply won't shutdown.

When I issue a shutdown (either from GUI, shutdown command or systemctl poweroff command), **the system will shutdown, and start again after a couple seconds**.

When I issue a "suspend" via systemctl, the screens turns off, but the fans are still running.

On Windows 10, I face no such problem.

There seems to be some incompatibility between Ubuntu and my hardware, but I have no idea how to go and troubleshoot this.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Welcome to askUbuntu! This seems like a power management issue. Is it a laptop or desktop computer?

Comment: Hello! This is a desktop computer, BIOS is up to date.

Comment: Does "journalctl --boot=-1" show any errors during the shutdown sequence? It may shut down but doesn't power off, hence why the screen turns black but the fans are still spinning

Comment: I'm not seeing any error:


    avril 28 01:23:32 Desktop-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
    [...]
    avril 28 01:23:32 Desktop-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
    avril 28 01:23:32 Desktop-Ubuntu systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service: Succeeded.
    avril 28 01:23:32 Desktop-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Finished Power-Off.
    avril 28 01:23:32 Desktop-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Reached target Power-Off.
    avril 28 01:23:32 Desktop-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Shutting down.